# Visual Studio 2015 keeps running old code/build

Tags: web, visual-studio-2015, build

I am currently working on a web project and I am having a problem where Visual Studio 2015 is not running the latest build.  I know that there are already some questions about this problem but I still could not fix this issue.

I have tried the following but still did not make any improvements:

- Closing Visual Studio
- Closing the project
- Clean and Re-build solution
- Deleting the bin folder
- Deleting the debug folder
- Tools -> Options -> Projects and    Solutions -> Build and Run:  "On
  Run, when projects are out of date"    set to "Always Build"

Any help, please?

Comment: try to close your local IIS..then check

Comment: Still did not work :/

Comment: did you try to restart you AppPool?

Comment: I have restarted my AppPool and it worked! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

So, the following is the answer how the above problem can be solved.

1. From the Administrative Tools, select IIS Manager
2. Click on Application Pools
3. Restart the App Pool